# Add version to xml node

Tags: xml, excel, vba

I am using Excel VBA to create and XML file and need to add version=1.0 attribute to a node. The format I need is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<VanwykXML version="1.0">
```

What I am currently coding is:

```
Sub FormulaBuilderSubmit()
Set oXMLDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
Set oPI = oXMLDoc.createProcessingInstruction("xml", "version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" standalone=""no""")
Set oRoot = oXMLDoc.createNode(1, "VanwykXML", "")
oXMLDoc.appendChild oRoot
oXMLDoc.InsertBefore oPI, oXMLDoc.ChildNodes.Item(0)
```

When I try adding version=1.0 to the createNode method it adds xmlns="" in each node which I don't want.

Any tips?

Thanks,
Maggie

Comment: Why do you need `standalone="no"`? I have no experience with XML in VBA but it might help to set this to "yes" or omit it. The empty `xmlns=""` declares a *non-existant default namespace*. So this is - assumably - not wrong (semantically).

Comment: I need standalone="no" because that is a requirement of the software that is using this XML. Also that software will error if I have the xlmns="" so I need another way to add the version. Is there a way to add version without xlmns=""?? or another method I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oXMLDoc.createNode creates an element. 
Add an attribute with 
Call oRoot.SetAttribute( "version", "1.0")

Here's the function

```
Set oXMLDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
Set oPI = oXMLDoc.createProcessingInstruction("xml", "version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" standalone=""no""")
Set oRoot = oXMLDoc.createNode(1, "VanwykXML", "")
Call oRoot.setAttribute("version", "1.0")
oXMLDoc.appendChild oRoot
oXMLDoc.InsertBefore oPI, oXMLDoc.ChildNodes.Item(0)
MsgBox oXMLDoc.XML
```